# Using JSP to paint a part of page other wise painted by Servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets

I am updating an age old application that paints its page using a Servlet. I want to add something to that page and really want to stop adding to that Servlet file.

Is there a way I could paint a part of a page using JSP and all other using Servlet.

Comment: Ajax, or jsp:include

Comment: No. OP is asking how to include a JSP from a Servlet, not how to include a JSP from a JSP.

Comment: An alternative approach would be to generate the content using some other templating language e.g. http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/index.html  and then simply insert the the HTML generated by the template at the relevant points. This would allow you to pull some/all of the HTML generation out of Java code in the Servlet and into the templates. You could do this using JSP but Velocity or similar is probably a more straightforward solution.

Answer (score -2):

Yes of course, you can use the

```
`<jsp:include page="content.jsp">`
```

or

```
`<%@include file="content.jsp"%>`
```

If your content is static(copy and paste), you can use

```
`<%@include file="content.jsp"%>`
```

The

```
`<%@include file="content.jsp">`
```

directive is similiar to "#include" in C programming, including the all contents of the included file and then compiling it like it is part of the including file. Also the included file can be any type (including HTML or text).

Comment: OP is asking how to include a JSP from a Servlet, not how to include a JSP from a JSP.